# Java stream sort 2 variables ascending/desending

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator, java-stream

I want to sort seq1 ascending and seq2 descending so I do this:

```
list = list.stream().sorted(comparing(AClass::getSeq1).thenComparing(        
   AClass::getSeq2).reversed()).collect(toList());
```

But the result come out as both seq1 and seq2 are sorted in descending order.

I can do this to make seq1 ascending and seq2 descending:

```
sorted(comparing(AClass::getSeq1)
   .reversed().thenComparing(AClass::getSeq2).reversed()
```

What is really the correct way to do this?

Comment: In the future, please provide your `import static` statements.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In your first example, `reversed` is applied to the whole comparator which compares seq1 then seq2 in ascending order.

What you need is to reverse the second comparison only, which can be done, for example, with:

```
import static java.util.Collections.reverseOrder;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

list = list.stream().sorted(
                        comparing(AClass::getSeq1)
                       .thenComparing(reverseOrder(comparing(AClass::getSeq2))))
                       .collect(toList());


//or you could also write:

list = list.stream().sorted(
                        comparing(AClass::getSeq1)
                       .thenComparing(comparing(AClass::getSeq2).reversed()))
                       .collect(toList());
```

Comment: Wow! there are more than one ways to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: [`.thenComparing(AClass::getSeq2, reverseOrder())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-) is also possible and will be the winner regarding source code length (what a close match)…

Comment: Thank you for adding the `import static` statements. They really should have been in the question...

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this behavior in java 7?

Comment: @stackMan10 Yes sure with a custom Comparator using an anonymous inner class. I'm sure you can find many questions on this on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Observations of the algebra:

In your first example: (left associative)

```
comparing.thenComparing.reversed = (comparing.thenComparing).reversed
```

In your second example: (distributive of `reversed`)

```
comparing.reversed.thenComparing.reversed 
= ((comparing.reversed).thenComparing).reversed
= ((comparing.reversed.reversed).(thenComparing.reversed))
= (comparing).(thenComparing.reversed)
```

This is stable and still always give what you want, but definitely not the right way to do it.

(this is a comment but too long for the formatting)