# How to use Java Comparator to sort an ArrayList using two parameters?

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I have used Java Comparator to sort an ArrayList of Word objects in descending order of Word frequency attribute. The Word objects are created by first using a hashmap to read the words from a .txt file and then convert the hashmap to an ArrayList of Word objects. I would like to then sort the words that have the same frequency by alphabetical order.

```
   while (reader.hasNext()) {
            word = reader.next().toLowerCase();
            word = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
            word = word.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
            if (!word.contains("0") || !word.contains("1") || !word.contains("2") || !word.contains("3") || !word.contains("4") || !word.contains("5") || !word.contains("6") || !word.contains("7") || !word.contains("8") || !word.contains("9") || !word.contains("-") || !word.contains("_")) {
                // This is equivalent to searching every word in the list via hashing (O(1))
                if(!frequencyMap.containsKey(word)) {
                     frequencyMap.put(word, 1);
                } else {
                        // We have already seen the word, increase frequency.
                        frequencyMap.put(word, frequencyMap.get(word) + 1);
                }
            }
            counter++;
        }

 for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : frequencyMap.entrySet()) {
    Word word = new Word(entry.getKey());
    word.frequency = entry.getValue();
    wordList.add(word);
 }
 Collections.sort(wordList, Word.WordFrequency);

public class Word {

    String value;
    int frequency;

    public Word(String v) {
        value = v;
        frequency = 1;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public int getFrequency() {
        return frequency;
    }

    public static Comparator<Word> WordFrequency = new Comparator<Word>() {
        public int compare(Word w1, Word w2) {
            int w1Frequency = w1.getFrequency();
            int w2Frequency = w2.getFrequency();
            return w2Frequency-w1Frequency;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: `if (w2Frequency - w1Frequency == 0) { return /* compareTheStrings*/; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java stream sort 2 variables ascending/desending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382453/java-stream-sort-2-variables-ascending-desending)

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks for the help, if you want to post an answer here's what I went with: `if (w1Frequency == w2Frequency) {
    return w1.getValue().compareTo(w2.getValue());
   } else {
    return w2Frequency-w1Frequency;
   }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `thenComparing` method, which allows you to supply a comparison key for when there are ties:

```
// sort using 'd' will sort 1st alphabetically, then by length
// (this is a totally arbitrary example)
Comparator<String> c = String::compareTo;
Comparator<String> d = c.thenComparing(s -> s.length());
```