# Get Highest Score from ArrayList Using Java Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I would like to get the highest score group by Id .If two highest score's are same then i would like get the highest score based on lowest Optional ID.I would like to get it in Java Stream.So far i am trying the following codes which is not working
Example :

Array List:

ID: 1 Score:80  OptionalId:1
ID: 1 Score:90  OptionalId:2
ID: 1 Score:90  OptionalId:3
ID: 2 Score:80  OptionalId:1
ID: 2 Score:100 OptionalId:3
ID: 2 Score:100 OptionalId:5

The result should be

ID: 1 Score 90  OptionalId:2
ID 2 Score 100  OptionalId:3

```
Map<Long, Optional<Person>> result1 = records.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId,
                          Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Person::getScore)),
                          Collector.minBy(Comparator.comparing(Person::getOptionalId))));


        for(Person ns: result1) {

            sb.append(ns.getBatchNumber());
            sb.append(',');
```

Comment: What happened to the scores with 80?

Comment: Score 80 should be eliminated.I will only take the highest score from each group.From the above example 80 is the lowest and there are two 90 which are highest.I will take only one 90 between two highest whichever have lowest optional ID.Currently the max by is taking the highest from randomly from two 90's which i don't want

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Vanished. Notice the `Collectors.maxBy` applied to the score.

Comment: `OptionalId` is really a `java.util.Optional`? or an `int/long`?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you start with a custom [`Comparator<Person>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which prioritizes a max of  `score` and then a min of `optionalId`. It's a good way to pass it to a variable for sake of brevity:

```
final Comparator<Person> comparator = Comparator
    .comparing(Person::getScore)                 // descending score first
    .thenComparing(Comparator                    // then ..
        .comparing(Person::getOptionalId)        // .. optionalId
        .reversed());                            // .. but ascending
```

Now use some collectors using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream).

- [`Collectors::groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) to group all the `Person`s by the `id` and downstream the value
- [`Collectors::reducing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to reduce all the `Person`s with the same `id` into one using the `Comparator<Person>` to get the one with the highest `score` and lowest `optionalId`.
- [`Collectors::collectingAndThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#collectingAndThen-java.util.stream.Collector-java.util.function.Function-) to flatten the structure from `Collection<Optional<Person>>` to `Collection<Person>` since any reducing operation results as [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) - this step is optional and might be skipped according to your sample.

Here is the code:

```
Collection<Person> filtered = records.stream()         // Stream<Person>
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(                    // from Map<Long, List<Person>>
        Person::getId,
        Collectors.collectingAndThen(                  // .. downstream to ..
                Collectors.reducing((a, b) ->          // .. Map<Long, Optional<Person>>
                    comparator.compare(a, b) > 0 ? a : b),
                Optional::get))                        // .. Map<Long, Person>
    .values();                                         // .. Collection<Person>
```

> [Person [id=1, score=90, optionalId=2], Person [id=2, score=100, optionalId=3]]

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions.I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

For a given Id value, there must be a Person. Existence of the Id value solely depends on the Person. So if there exists an Id, there must be a Person too. Therefore what is the point of having an `Optional<Person>` as the value of the map. In contrast, it makes more sense to merely have a `Person` instance as the value in the `map`. Here I am using the `toMap` collector in concert with the `BinaryOperator.maxBy` to get the work done. Here's how it looks. Notice how the `BinaryOperator.maxBy` is used as the `mergeFunction`.

```
Map<Integer, Person> maxPersonById = records.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getId, Function.identity(),
        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Person::getScore)
            .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Person::getOptionalId).reversed()))));
```

And here's the output for the above given input.

> ```
> {1=Person [id=1, score=90, optionalId=2], 2=Person [id=2, score=100, optionalId=3]}
> ```

Comment: This is the right answer, +1 for showing `Collectors.toMap` along ith `BinaryOperator.maxBy`, which is the best approach here.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following stream code which aggregates by `ID`, and then finds the max score using a two level sort, first by score, then, by optional ID in case of a tie for score:

```
import static java.util.Collections.reverseOrder;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

Map<Long, Optional<Person>> result1 = records.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId,
             Collectors.maxBy(
                 Comparator.comparing(Person::getScore)
                  .thenComparing(reverseOrder(comparing(Person::getOptionalId))))));

Optional[ID: 1 Score: 90 OptionalId: 2]
Optional[ID: 2 Score: 100 OptionalId: 3]
```

The trick here is to reverse the sorting order for *only* the optional ID, which we want to be ascending, not descending.  The sort order by default would be descending, because we are invoking `Collections.maxBy`.

I cite [this great SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382453/java-stream-sort-2-variables-ascending-desending) for help with the reverse syntax.  Also, I borrowed the boiler plate code from @mayamar to setup the following demo:

### Demo

(demo only for demonstration purposes)

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestions.I really appreciate it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this would only work if you assume that `OptionalId` is really a `long`, but it could be a `java.util.Optional`...

Comment: @Eugene I don't interpret the OP's use of the word "optional" to refer to the `Optional` class, but rather to that the secondary ID is just an optional piece of data which may or may not be used to break a tie.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a bit and introduced a helper class that compares score and optionalId.

```
public class T21Group {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> records = new ArrayList<>();
    records.add(new Person(1, 80, 1));
    records.add(new Person(1, 90, 2));
    records.add(new Person(1, 90, 3));
    records.add(new Person(2, 80, 1));
    records.add(new Person(2, 100, 3));
    records.add(new Person(2, 100, 5));

    Map<Long, Optional<Person>> result1 = records.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getId, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Pair::new))));

    for (Optional<Person> ns : result1.values()) {
        System.out.println(ns);
    }
}

public static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    long score;
    long optionalId;

    public Pair(Person p) {
        score = p.getScore();
        optionalId = p.getOptionalId();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair o) {
        if (this.score == o.score) {
            return Long.compare(o.optionalId, this.optionalId);
        }
        return Long.compare(this.score, o.score);
    }

}

public static class Person {
    private long id;
    private long score;
    private long optionalId;

    public Person(long id, long score, long optionalId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.score = score;
        this.optionalId = optionalId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ID: " + id + " Score: " + score + " OptionalId: " + optionalId;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(long score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public long getOptionalId() {
        return optionalId;
    }

    public void setOptionalId(long optionalId) {
        this.optionalId = optionalId;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You never check the optional value in case of a tied score.

Comment: Grrrr. Well it shouldn't be difficult to change the Comparator to use that value too. I take a look.